# How can I start tomcat7 in eclipse using terminal in ubuntu?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, terminal, tomcat7

I have a tomcat7 server created inside the eclipse and I want to start and stop the server using terminal in ubuntu. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can start or stop the tomcat in ubuntu terminal using "`sh startup.sh`" to start up and "`sh shutdown.sh`" to shut down. These shell scripts can be found in the "`$(tomcat_folder)/bin`". 
Hope it helps.

Comment: using this yes tomcat can be started. But I want to start tomcat in eclipse and use eclipse console as log.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the tomcat path that eclipse is using. Then navigate the that path in ubuntu terminal and simply

```
sh startup.sh // starts up the server
```

and

```
sh shutdown.sh // shuts down the server
```

Comment: using this yes tomcat can be started. But I want to start tomcat in eclipse and use eclipse console as log.

Comment: If you have a tomcat server inside Eclipse, Eclipse would use it whenever you run or debug your web application by default. Without any configuration, you can use it there.

Comment: no. I create war file and copy it webapps in tomcat.And then i run the application on my browser on local host.

Comment: what happens when you press the run or debug button for your web application in eclipse?

Comment: it is completely working by pressing the button. The thing is I want to do the same thing when I press the start button using terminal.Is there a way to do that?

Comment: when you run it in terminal stdout is set to terminal. I don't know how you can set it to eclipse!